# Double Integral with absolute value.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, absolute-value, multiple-integral

I'm trying to get
$$\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{2x}}y^2|x-y|dydx.$$
I'm struggling with that absolute value. I'm not sure how to "divide" the integral into two. I know that
$$|x-y|=\begin{cases} x-y &\text{ if }x\geq y, \\
y-x &\text{ if }x\leq y.\end{cases}$$
My problem is I have that $y=\sqrt{2x}$ in the top integral extreme.

Comment: When you have a problem like this, it is almost always a good idea to draw a picture of the regions in question. A good diagram will make the resolution almost obvious.

Comment: I draw the region, it is on the first quadrant...

Comment: Oh! I can divide it from $0$ to $x$ and from $x$ to $\sqrt{2x}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let draw a sketch for $\sqrt {2x}$ and $x$ then divide the region in two parts for $x-y\ge 0$ and $x-y<0$ and the integral accordingly.

[image]

Comment: I thought about that with the comment I got. I can integrante from $0$ to $x$ $(x-y)$ and from $x$ to $\sqrt{2x}$ $(y-x)$, right?

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín Yes exactly!

Comment: Thank you very much! The first thing I did was that diagram, but didn't realize to check that identity for the sum. Great.